# find expectation using probability generating function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

how to calculate $E[\frac{1}{1+X}]$ using probability generating function such as $E[ \int_0^1z^X dz]$ ? and also what is the relation between them? what is z in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z$ is just a variable of integration. First note that $\int_0^{1} z^{X} dz=\frac {z^{X+1}} {X+1}|_0^{1}=\frac 1 {X+1}$. Hence $E\frac 1 {X+1} =E\int_0^{1} z^{X} dz=\int_0^{1} Ez^{X} dz$. The function $f(z)=Ez^{X}$ is called the generating function of $X$. If you know the distribution of $X$ then you can calculate and $f(z)$. Integrating this from $0$ to $1$ gives you the value of $E\frac 1 {X+1}$.